# Use result from query in same query?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL question, I'm wondering if the answers lies in using joins. I apologize in advance if the title is confusing or misleading.

I have 2 tables: Teams, Contractors

```
TEAMS
|team_id | location|
--------------------
|    1   |  space1 |
--------------------
|    2   |  space2 |
--------------------
|    3   |  space3 |
--------------------
```

---

```
CONTRACTORS
|cont_id | location| team_id|
-----------------------------
|    1   |  space1 |    1   |
-----------------------------
|    2   |  space1 |    0   |
-----------------------------
|    3   |  space3 |    3   |
-----------------------------
|    4   |  space3 |    3   |
-----------------------------
|    5   |  space3 |    0   |
-----------------------------
```

I would like to create a query that finds all the contractors that are at a specific location. The issue is, I only know the team_id. (`team_id = 0` in the CONTRACTORS table means the contractor is not currently part of a team).

For example, I'm given the `team_id = 3.` The team with `team_id = 3` is located at space3. I want to find all the contractors that are located at space3 (cont_id = 3, 4, 5 in this example).

Is there a way to achieve this with a single MySQL query? Or do I need to perform a query to get the location of the team, and then a 2nd query to find all contractors at that location?

Comment: Just a quick thank you to those who took a moment to help me out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select location 
from CONTRACTORS 
inner join TEAMS on TEAMS.location = CONTRACTORS.location and TEAMS.team_id = 3
```

Comment: I had to select CONTRACTORS.location, but otherwise this worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join

```
SELECT        t.*,c.* 
FROM          TEAMS 
INNER JOIN    CONTRACTORS c 
ON            c.team_id = t.team_id 
WHERE         t.team_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One SQL query:

```
SELECT cont_id
FROM teams, contractors
WHERE teams.location = contractors.location
AND teams.team_id = 3;
```

Replace '3' with the team you want.

**Note:** this query is only returning cont_id. You didn't specify what exactly you need, but I'm guessing at the very least you need the cont_id to identify the contractors.