# MySQL query joining

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL question. It is related to [this other question that I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398061/use-result-from-query-in-same-query), but slightly different.

I have 2 tables: Teams, Contractors

```
TEAMS
|team_id | location|
--------------------
|    1   |  space1 |
--------------------
|    2   |  space2 |
--------------------
|    3   |  space3 |
--------------------
|    4   |  space3 |
--------------------
```

---

```
CONTRACTORS
|cont_id | location| team_id|
-----------------------------
|    1   |  space1 |    1   |
-----------------------------
|    2   |  space1 |    0   |
-----------------------------
|    3   |  space3 |    3   |
-----------------------------
|    4   |  space3 |    3   |
-----------------------------
|    5   |  space3 |    0   |
-----------------------------
|    6   |  space3 |    4   |
-----------------------------
```

If I'm given a team_id, I would like to create a query that finds all the contractors that are at the location of the given team_id AND belong only to the given team_id or with a `team_id = 0`.  (`team_id = 0` in the CONTRACTORS table means the contractor is not currently part of a team).

For example, I'm given the `team_id = 3.` The team with `team_id = 3` is located at space3. I want to find the contractors that are located at space3 and belong only to `team_id = 3` or `team_id = 0` (cont_id = 3, 4, 5 in this example).

Is there a way to achieve this with a single MySQL query?

Comment: I have updated my answer refer to it

Comment: for 5 the team_id is 0 and not 3, there is mistake in the query, mine works fine..!!!

Comment: i have updated my answer refere to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select cont_id,team_id,location
FROM CONTRACTORS
where team_id = 3 or
      team_id =0 and
      location In
                 (
                    SElect location
                    from TEAMS
                    where team_id=3
                  )
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c73eb/52)

**Output:**

[image]

With Joins You can do this way

```
SELECT C.cont_id ,C.team_id,T.location 
FROM TEAMS T
LEFT JOIN CONTRACTORS C 
ON T.location = C.location
AND (T.team_id = C.team_id OR C.team_id = 0)
where T.team_id= 3
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c73eb/57)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked as needed. I was not aware you could do nested queries. I'll have to read about this. Thanks again.

Comment: @but see teamid is returning 3 but actually it is 0 right??

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this

```
SELECT C.cont_id ,T.team_id,T.locations
FROM TEAM T
LEFT JOIN CONTRACTORS C ON T.team_id = C.team_id OR C.team_id = 0
WHERE T.team_id = 3
```

Comment: The ON clause needs to use OR rather than AND , but otherwise this would be my choice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Using the AND, the results were way off. When using OR as Kickstart suggested, it gave me cont_id = 2,3,4,5. So it's giving me all contractors with team_id = 0. I'm looking for just the contractors of the given team, and those in the same location but without a team.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select cont_id, c.team_id, c.location 
from CONTRACTORS c join TEAM t
on c.team_id = t.team_id 
where c.team_id = GIVEN_TEAM_ID or c.team_id = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I tried this, it didn't give me any of the contractors that had team_id = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative avoiding a sub query:-

```
SELECT C.cont_id ,T.team_id,T.location 
FROM TEAMS T
LEFT JOIN CONTRACTORS C 
ON T.location = C.location
AND (T.team_id = C.team_id OR C.team_id = 0)
WHERE T.team_id = 3
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9efd/1

Comment: for 5 the team_id is 0 and not 3, there is mistake in the query, mine works fine..

Comment: For cont_id = 5 the team_id is 0 and not 3. Your answer is not correct

Comment: It is specifying the team id in the WHERE. It is possible that the OP wants either the team id they have specified to look up or the team the unassigned contractor is already in. Depends whether the OP wants a query which returns the team when there are no matching contractors at all (which is why it is using a left join).